# ASP.NEt - Edit Html before send to client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net mvc 3 application and I need to add some html to html generated by Response.Redirect(). This html should be on this page only if page is redirect from this controller. Any solution?

```
 public class MyController : Controller
 {
    public ActionResult MyAction(string name)
    {
         Response.Redirect("/Test/Work");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does Response.Redirect produce any HTTP body at all, or just the headers?

Comment: There is no html generated for a `Response.Redirect`. What you need to do is in your `/text/work` action method is check the referrer or use `TempData` to determine if it's a redirect and then show your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is NO HTML associated with `Response.Redirect` - it works on the `HTTP` level (code `302`)... see MSDN for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx .

**EDIT - as per comments:**

IF you want to return HTML or similar (this has NOTHING to do with redirect!) you can call `Content`.

For details see

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505216.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269.aspx

Comment: Is any solution to change page html if page is requested from my controller?

Comment: instead of redirecting you can return HTML or whatever you want... see my EDIT above... and don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...